# Getting line of code from code address

Tags: c++, c, gcc, debug-symbols

I am able to get what function an address corresponds to by going through the .map file.  I want to take it one step further and also print the line of code where the address corresponds to.  The address I am referring to is the `lr` register.  I understand the `lr` would point to the line of code after the previous function call but getting that line would still be helpful.

Comment: Maybe `addr2line` can help you.

Comment: If you are inside `gdb`, you can use `list *0xblahblah`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Wow, that was quick.  I wanted to get the line of from a code address.  Yes, addr2line does the job.  I had written my code in C++, so I guess I could use popen() to get addr2line's output.

Comment: If you want to do it programatically, you can use `backtrace_symbols()` from `execinfo.h`.

Comment: Ok, I'm a little confused about `backtrace`.  Does it take as input just the code addresses or the entire stack frame?  The stack frame that I have is not from the calling process but from somewhere else.

Comment: @user2233706: Just code addresses.

Comment: I see no way to specify the binary.  My stack is not from the program I'm writing.

Comment: addr2line works fine for me.  I'm not sure what the mods want to do.  Maybe give the points to RedX?